# Time complexity for this snippet

Tags: c++, tree

I am solving the following question from [LeetCode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-zigzag-level-order-traversal/description/):

> Given a binary tree, return the zigzag level order traversal of its nodes' values. (ie, from left to right, then right to left for the next level and alternate between).

For the tree:

```
    3
   / \
  9  20
    /  \
   15   7
```

The answer is:

```
[
  [3],
  [20,9],
  [15,7]
]
```

I came up with the following code:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> result;

    void zigzagLevelOrderUtil(TreeNode* root, int level) {
        if(root==NULL) return;

        if(result.size()==level)
            result.push_back(vector<int>());

        result[level].push_back(root->val);
        zigzagLevelOrderUtil(root->left, level+1);
        zigzagLevelOrderUtil(root->right, level+1);
    }

    vector<vector<int>> zigzagLevelOrder(TreeNode* root) {
        result.clear();
        zigzagLevelOrderUtil(root, 0);

        for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++)
            if(i%2!=0)
                reverse(result[i].begin(), result[i].end());        //I think the complexity here is O(hn)

        return result;
    }
};
```

However, I am not sure about the complexity - is it `O(hn)` (where `h` is the height and `n` is the number of nodes); or is it just `O(h)`.  I am confused because technically, I am working (reversing) only on half of `h`; and I think it can have at max `n/2` nodes.  [Please see the comment in the code].

Could someone please confirm?  Thanks!

Comment: Since you're vsiting all `n` nodes it can't be smaller than O/n) (and you can't ignore `n`).

Comment: So, do you mean to say it is `O(hn)`?

Comment: I'm too tired to work out all the details, but that seems plausible. (If you can avoid the post-traversal reversal, you get rid of the `h`.)

Comment: @molbdnilo, well, the post-traversal reversal is imperative since that is what the question asks for.  If this code above is not `O(n)`, then I will have to think some other way of doing it.  That's why I seek the answer to this question.  I am undecided as to whether this is `O(hn)` or `O(n)`.

Comment: @molbdnilo, how about if we call it `O(n)`, because in case of large inputs, `h<<n` (as @legalalien seems to point out in his answer)?

Comment: `h` is at least `lg n`, which is not `<< n`. (By that reasoning, heapsort would be O(n).) And you're allowed to gather each level in the intended order while traversing the tree - there is nothing in the question that requires you to traverse the tree first and then reverse.

Comment: It is O(n) not because h << n. Complexity is not O(h.n), it is O(h+n) and h is insignificant in that case. Look at my walk-through.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see.

Since there are h elements in result vector one can say the complexity is O(h.n) but in reality it is O(n).

Why is that? Because 'std::reverse' function has O(n) complexity. It seems like O(h.n) because you have h amount of vectors in result vector. But remember in total all that vectors have n elements which are the nodes of the tree.

Let's say we have a full binary tree with 3 levels including the root level. The result vector is something like [[x], [y, z], [t, w, m, n]]. 1 operation for result[0] and 1 for inner vector 0, 1 operation for result[1] and 2 for inner vector 1, 1 operation for result[2] and 4 for inner vector 2. So we have 10 operations which are equal to h+n operations. (For making our job easy, not only even indexes are processed but all of them are.)

As the inner vectors grow bigger the operation in which we go to the next index of outer vector is becoming insignificant. The time complexity is O(h+n) as seen in the example but h < n and so we can say it is O(n) complexity.

Comment: When you say _'1 operation for result[0] and 1 for inner vector 0'_, could you please emphasize which operation you mean?  I don't think you mean reversing, because the way I understand your terms, it would be just _'1 operation for result[0]'_ (without _'`1` for inner vector 0'_).  As per your example, `[[x], [y, z], [t, w, m, n]]` the result of this so-called operation would be `[[x], [z, y], [n, m, w, t]]` - 1 operation for each `result`.  Since you apparently consider even this _'operation for inner vector'_, I am not sure if the analysis is totally correct.

Comment: @P.K. For inner vector 0 it is the check operation that if the first equals the last. If we dig down deeper we see the complexity of reverse function goes to O(n) as it grows bigger. Because in the inner vector 1 it is 3 ops. actually check, swap, check... It goes like 1, 3, 5, 7 instead of 0, 2, 4, 6.

Comment: @P.K. but we played it like it is 2, 4, 6 ,8... and for simplicity divided it by 2.